Exception when shutting down service using Eureka - Spring Cloud
I am learning about Spring Cloud and I'm trying to configure a registry server with 2 simple microservices. Everything works fine so far but when I shutdown one of my services it displays an exception while Unregestering from Eureka. The error is as follows:
2024-04-19T21:47:11.812+02:00  INFO 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2024-04-19T21:47:14.826+02:00  INFO 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2024-04-19T21:47:14.831+02:00  INFO 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/} exception=Connection pool shut down stacktrace=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.hc.core5.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:38)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.lease(StrictConnPool.java:176)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.lease(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.acquireEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:103)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:125)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient.executeOpen(HttpClient.java:183)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:95)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:112)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateTransportClientFactory.lambda$restTemplate$0(RestTemplateTransportClientFactory.java:143)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:72)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:889)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.cancel(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:87)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:91)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:916)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:892)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:145)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:114)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

2024-04-19T21:47:14.832+02:00  WARN 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Connection pool shut down
2024-04-19T21:47:14.836+02:00  INFO 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=Connection pool shut down stacktrace=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.hc.core5.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:38)
    at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.lease(StrictConnPool.java:176)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.lease(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.acquireEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:103)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:125)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient.executeOpen(HttpClient.java:183)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:95)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:112)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateTransportClientFactory.lambda$restTemplate$0(RestTemplateTransportClientFactory.java:143)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:72)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:889)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.cancel(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:87)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:916)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:892)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:145)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:114)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

2024-04-19T21:47:14.836+02:00  WARN 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Connection pool shut down
2024-04-19T21:47:14.836+02:00 ERROR 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ARTICULOS-SERVICE/host.docker.internal:ARTICULOS-SERVICE:1700 - de-registration failedCannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:916) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:892) ~[eureka-client-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:415) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:202) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:195) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:136) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1147) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:145) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:114) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-04-19T21:47:14.849+02:00  INFO 16392 --- [ARTICULOS-SERVICE] [ionShutdownHook] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient

Process finished with exit code 130

Service 1:
application.properties
spring.application.name=ARTICULOS-SERVICE
server.port=1700

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybartpv
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent

spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null


eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

AppConfig
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}

Service:
@Service
public class ArticulosServiceImpl implements ArticulosService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    ArticulosServiceImpl(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Articulo> getArticulos() {
        this.a();
        return null
    }

    private void a() {
        HttpEntity<String> a = this.restTemplate.exchange("http://TEST-SERVICE/", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}

Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping(URIConstants.ARTICULOS_URI)
public class ArticulosControllerImpl implements ArticulosController {
    private final ArticulosService articulosService;

    @Autowired
    ArticulosControllerImpl(final ArticulosService articulosService){
        this.articulosService = articulosService;
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getArticulos() {
        this.articulosService.getArticulos()
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}

Service 2
application.properties
spring.application.name=TEST-SERVICE
server.port=1701

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

Controller
@RestController("/")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> a() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
}

Registry service:
application.properties:
spring.application.name=REGISTRY-TEST

server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

AppConfig:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class RegistrytestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistrytestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

What am I missing here? I don't like seeing this error every time I shutdown my service

This is caused by the following regression: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4275. The problematic change has been reverted and the issue will be removed in the next patch.
